# powershell outlook showing content from other e-mail

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-3.0

I have this powershell script that prints SenderEmailAddress, to and subject.
Now the problem is when asking for content `get-content  $txtContent | Select -Index 23` I get the content from another e-mail. Maybe there is a method to clear the cache or something because the content I get is from the previous e-mail and I don't know how to fix this.

```
$txtContent= "C:\test.txt";
$matchString= "info@blabla.com";

$olFolderInbox = 6
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;
$mapi = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)

$inbox.items | Select -Last 1 SenderEmailAddress,to,subject
$inbox.items | where { $_.SenderEmailAddress -match $matchString }  | Out-File $txtContent

get-content  $txtContent | Select -Index 23
```

When using `get-content  $txtContent` I get the content of the e-mail that I need. But when I need the line 23 I get the content from another, previous e-mail

Comment: well, can you open up the txt file and verify what's in the file? i doubt this might work poorly, since the get-content is braindead straightforward

Comment: Remember, array-indices are zero-based, so `-Index 23` will fetch line 24 - use `Select -Index 22` to grab the 23rd line